# Json Fields search with django unexpected behavior

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, orm

Hi guys Im seeing a behavior than i don't understand in django postgres json search.
Im Using django 1.11 and django orm with psycopg2 driver.

It goes as follows:

The json in the model field looks like this.

```
{"2018": [1, 2, 3]}
```

If I use this query:

```
models.mymodel.objects.filter(jsonfield__2018__contains=1)
Out[97]: <QuerySet []>
```

So as you can see i get an empty query.

Then I tried to do this just for testing purposes.
New Json:

```
[ {"2018": [1, 2, 3]}]
```

New Query:

```
models.mymodel.objects.filter(jsonfield__0__2018__contains=1)
Out[98]: <QuerySet []>
```

It still gives me no response.

Then I finally tried this.
New Json:

```
[ {"2018_1": [1, 2, 3]}]
```

New Query:

```
models.mymodel.objects.filter(jsonfield__0__2018_1__contains=1)
Out[100]: <QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object>]>
```

This one responds and I cannot wrap my head around it. Does anyone know why is this?

Comment: can you try this .. {"abc": [1, 2, 3]}   .. models.mymodel.objects.filter(jsonfield__abc__contains=1)  .. if that works then we know the issue. Django doesn't allow numeric to be model field names.

Comment: Dude thank you allot good catch it effectively is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't allow numeric only field names in models. I think this limitation arises from some of the Database column name limitations (eg. In MySQL, Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits).

And Django has field like behavior for JSON keys, so i assume the issue could be due to the same. You can try with an alphanumberic JSON key and test the same.